# windows phone mango 7.1 API/controller for GUI

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm new to wp development. I got the basic idea how to develop basic GUI. I would like to do something similar like this http://www.simile-widgets.org/timeline/ where we can scroll the contents in the same page by a mouse pointer drag. So which controller will be a right choice to startup my GUI. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The basic control for scrolling a region of the UI via a drag operation is a `ScrollViewer`. Simply place your content, which is larger than the viewing are, within a `ScrollViewer` and off you go ...

```
<ScrollViewer>
  ... large content goes here
</ScrollViewer>
```